# Elementor Pro: Disable newly added Woocommerce widgets

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, endpoint, elementor

I have written a plugin for woocommerce to send woocommerce shipping methods through API.
When I update my **elementor pro** to **v3.5**, in which elementor adds some widgets to edit woocommerce default pages, my Code brokes and returns an error with "-1" as the error message.
I am searching for a solution to disable woocommerce widgets from elementor pro v3.5 and later

Answer (score 0):

I am not an Elementor pro however, reading the documentation here: [https://developers.elementor.com/docs/managers/unregistering-widgets/][1] have you tried something like this?:

```
/**
 * Unregister Elementor widgets.
 *
 * @param \Elementor\Widgets_Manager $widgets_manager Elementor widgets manager.
 * @return void
 */
function unregister_widgets( $widgets_manager ) {

    $widgets_manager->unregister( 'woocommerce' );

}
add_action( 'elementor/widgets/register', 'unregister_widgets' );
```

**Note**: In the example its unregistering the woocommerce widget, but I am not truly sure about the name of the woocommerce-elements.